# ins-20802 - oracle net configuration assistant failed during installation - centos 7

Tags: oracle, centos, oracle12c, centos7

Hello I am trying to folow the [manual](http://www.unixmen.com/install-oracle-database-12c-centos-7/) for installing the Oracle 12c. Actually it was already installed on the machine, and then deinstalled.

During installiation I get the "[ins-20802] oracle net configuration assistant failed during installation" error window. And proposed detail log file, where I can see:

```
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: starting read loop.
INFO: Read: 
WARNING: Skipping line: 
INFO: End of argument passing to stdin
INFO: Read: Parsing command line arguments:
WARNING: Skipping line: Parsing command line arguments:
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "orahome" = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "orahome" = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "orahnam" = OraDB12Home1
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "orahnam" = OraDB12Home1
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "instype" = typical
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "instype" = typical
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "inscomp" = client,oraclenet,javavm,server,ano
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "insprtcl" = tcp
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "cfg" = local
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "cfg" = local
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "authadp" = NO_VALUE
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "responsefile" = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "responsefile" = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "silent" = true
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "silent" = true
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Parameter "ouiinternal" = true
WARNING: Skipping line:     Parameter "ouiinternal" = true
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read: Done parsing command line arguments.
WARNING: Skipping line: Done parsing command line arguments.
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read: Oracle Net Services Configuration:
WARNING: Skipping line: Oracle Net Services Configuration:
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read: Profile configuration complete.
WARNING: Skipping line: Profile configuration complete.
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read: Oracle Net Listener Startup:
WARNING: Skipping line: Oracle Net Listener Startup:
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Running Listener Control: 
WARNING: Skipping line:     Running Listener Control: 
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:       /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin/lsnrctl start LISTENER
WARNING: Skipping line:       /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin/lsnrctl start LISTENER
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Listener Control complete.
WARNING: Skipping line:     Listener Control complete.
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read:     Listener start failed.
WARNING: Skipping line:     Listener start failed.
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read: Check the trace file for details: /u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraDB12Home1-1504033PM3901.log
WARNING: Skipping line: Check the trace file for details: /u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/netca/trace_OraDB12Home1-1504033PM3901.log
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Read: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
WARNING: Skipping line: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
INFO: Exceeded the number of arguments passed to stdin. CurrentCount:1 Total args:0
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Net Configuration Assistant
```

Ans the corresponding trace_OraDB12Home1-1504033PM3901.log:

```
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.329 MSK ] [OracleHome.getVersion:1059]  Current Version From Inventory: 12.1.0.2.0
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.329 MSK ] [InitialSetup.<init>:4151]  Admin location is: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.718 MSK ] [ConfigureProfile.setProfileParam:140]  Setting NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH: (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.735 MSK ] [HAUtils.getCurrentOracleHome:593]  Oracle home from system property: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.735 MSK ] [HAUtils.getConfiguredGridHome:1343]  ----- Getting CRS HOME ----
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.737 MSK ] [UnixSystem.getCRSHome:2878]  olrFileName = /etc/oracle/olr.loc
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.795 MSK ] [HAUtils.getHASHome:1500]  Failed to get HAS home.
PRCI-1144 : Failed to retrieve Oracle Grid Infrastructure home path
PRKC-1144 : File "/etc/oracle/olr.loc" not found.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.795 MSK ] [InitialSetup.checkHAConfiguration:4808]  HA Server is NOT configured.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.797 MSK ] [NetCAResponseFile.<init>:75]  Response file initialized: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/install/netca_typ.rsp
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.798 MSK ] [NetCAResponseFile.getInstalledComponents:114]  Installed components from response file: server, net8, javavm
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.798 MSK ] [NetCAResponseFile.getVirtualHost:171]  Virtual Host from response file: null
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.799 MSK ] [SilentConfigure.performSilentConfigure:198]  Typical profile configuration.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.801 MSK ] [ConfigureProfile.setProfileParam:140]  Setting NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH: (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.802 MSK ] [SilentConfigure.performSilentConfigure:206]  Typical listener configuration.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.839 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isHASConfigured:1596]  Calling SRVM api to check if Oracle Restart is configured ...
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.840 MSK ] [HAUtils.getCurrentOracleHome:593]  Oracle home from system property: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.840 MSK ] [HAUtils.getConfiguredGridHome:1343]  ----- Getting CRS HOME ----
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.840 MSK ] [UnixSystem.getCRSHome:2878]  olrFileName = /etc/oracle/olr.loc
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.841 MSK ] [HAUtils.getHASHome:1500]  Failed to get HAS home.
PRCI-1144 : Failed to retrieve Oracle Grid Infrastructure home path
PRKC-1144 : File "/etc/oracle/olr.loc" not found.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.841 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isHASConfigured:1607]  Is Oracle Restart configured: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.841 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isHASRunning:1636]  Is Oracle Restart running: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.842 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.listenerExists:396]  Is listener "LISTENER" already exists: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.842 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.typicalConfigure:257]  Checking for free port in range: 1521-1540
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.842 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.validateEndPoint:1059]  Validating end-point: TCP:1521
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.944 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1131]  Checking if port 1521 is free on local machine...
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.945 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1146]  InetAddress.getByName(127.0.0.1): /127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.945 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1148]  Local host IP address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.945 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1150]  Local host name: localhost.localdomain
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.945 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1166]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1, Is IPv6 Address: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.946 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1169]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1, Is Link-Local Address: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.946 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1194]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521, IP Address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.968 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1197]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.968 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1166]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, Is IPv6 Address: true
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.968 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1169]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, Is Link-Local Address: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.968 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1194]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521, IP Address: localhost.localdomain/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.969 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1197]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.969 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1209]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521, Local IP Address: /127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.969 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1213]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.969 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1219]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.970 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1222]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.970 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1242]  Returning is Port 1521 free: true
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.970 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.validateEndPoint:1114]  Validation...Complete for TCP/TCPS.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:06.970 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.typicalConfigure:274]  Using port: 1521
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.684 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1131]  Checking if port 1521 is free on local machine...
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.685 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1146]  InetAddress.getByName(127.0.0.1): /127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.686 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1148]  Local host IP address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.686 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1150]  Local host name: localhost.localdomain
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.687 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1166]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1, Is IPv6 Address: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.687 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1169]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1, Is Link-Local Address: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.687 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1194]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521, IP Address: localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.688 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1197]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.688 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1166]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, Is IPv6 Address: true
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.689 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1169]  IP Address: localhost.localdomain/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, Is Link-Local Address: false
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.689 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1194]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521, IP Address: localhost.localdomain/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.689 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1197]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.690 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1209]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521, Local IP Address: /127.0.0.1
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.690 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1213]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.691 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1219]  Creating ServerSocket on Port:1521
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.691 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1222]  Created ServerSocket successfully.
[main] [ 2015-04-03 15:39:08.692 MSK ] [ConfigureListener.isPortFree:1242]  Returning is Port 1521 free: true
```

Maybe problem is because:

```
PRCI-1144 : Failed to retrieve Oracle Grid Infrastructure home path
PRKC-1144 : File "/etc/oracle/olr.loc" not found.
```

Any ideas what I am dooing wrong and how finally install the Oracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason for this exception. If somebody will face the same problem just create /etc/oracle folder and give to it 777 permissions. For me it helped

Comment: Setting permissions on anything to `777` is a very bad idea and will compromise the security of your system. Someone in a deleted answer claims that the docs say it should be `775` instead, which is more reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

I also got error "[INS-20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed" while installing Oracle 12c (12.2.0.1.4) on Centos7.

In my case the error went away after adding an entry in the /etc/hosts file with the hostname and its local network IP.

After that change the installation was able to finish successfully.

Resulting /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6


192.168.1.100  centos100
```

Comment: This solved my problem while trying to install GI 12.2.0.1 . I forgot to add the entry on hosts file. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

777 is not the solution, it is making your system vulnerable. As suggested in oracle docs, the dir privileges should be 775.

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer you're critiquing. This is, itself, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

For me in Windows 10 the solution was to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: For Win10, the MSVC 2010 is not available anymore from MS, but it is included in the Oracle install. The problem is just the error in he `oraparam.ini` file as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754744/111036): correct the file to replace `MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x64.exe` with `MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x86.exe`