# Oracle 12c client installer error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to install Oracle client 12.1.0.2.0 (32-bit) on a completely clean copy of windows Server 2012, and I'm hitting a problem.

The installer runs fine until it gets to the final part - the net configuration assistant. An error message appears and says "[INS-20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed.". Here's the relevant part of the log file that is generated (I can post the entire thing if requested, but here's the bit with the actual error occurs):

```
INFO: Read: UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: oranjni12
INFO: Stderr Read: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.jniGetOracleHome()Ljava/lang/String;
WARNING: Skipping line: UnsatisfiedLinkError exception loading native library: oranjni12
INFO: Read: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\app\ORACLE_USER\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN\oranjni12.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
INFO: Stderr Read:  at oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.jniGetOracleHome(Native Method)
INFO: Stderr Read:  at oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.getOracleHome(Unknown Source)
INFO: Stderr Read:  at oracle.net.ca.NetCALogger.getOracleHome(NetCALogger.java:230)
INFO: Stderr Read:  at oracle.net.ca.NetCALogger.initOracleParameters(NetCALogger.java:215)
INFO: Stderr Read:  at oracle.net.ca.NetCALogger.initLogger(NetCALogger.java:130)
INFO: Stderr Read:  at oracle.net.ca.NetCA.main(NetCA.java:433)
WARNING: Skipping line: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\app\ORACLE_USER\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN\oranjni12.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
INFO: Read: 
WARNING: Skipping line: 
INFO: Read: Error: oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.jniGetOracleHome()Ljava/lang/String;
WARNING: Skipping line: Error: oracle.net.common.NetGetEnv.jniGetOracleHome()Ljava/lang/String;
INFO: Read: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
WARNING: Skipping line: Oracle Net Services configuration failed.  The exit code is 1
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Net Configuration Assistant
```

Here are a few things I have tried:

- turning the firewall off
- disconnecting from network (clutching at straws!)
- running the installer as administrator
- re-downloading the client installer from Oracle, in case it had somehow been corrupted

None of these things made any difference. I have successfully installed this exact version of the client on a Windows Server 2012 PC in the past and it worked fine...

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 client needs the MSVC 2010 redistributable to be installed first.

I got it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Once installed the Oracle client installer runs fine! Couldn't find this anywhere in the Oracle documentation, and the error message is not helpful at all...

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem!  Bad oracle for not including dependencies!

Comment: The MSVC 2010 is not available anymore from MS, but it is included in the Oracle install. The problem is just the error in he oraparam.ini file as described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754744/111036)

Answer (score 5):

Quick, clean easy fix:-

There is a bug in the 32-bit Oracle Installer file `./install/oraparam.ini`, it’s trying to install the 64-bit version of **MSVC** instead of the 32-bit version.

1. Open `install/oraparam.ini`
2. Replace   `MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x64.exe`
   with
   `MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x86.exe`
3. Save
4. Run installer

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem "[INS-20802] Oracle Net Configuration Assistant failed" and trying to install many times Oracle12cR2 on Windows1O. I installed Oracle12cR1 without problems, so I realized that "vcredist_x64.exe" file is even latest than the file I downloaded before from Microsoft webpage.

In this case, I uninstalled Oracle12cR1 and Installed again the Oracle12cR2 version, but using the vcredist_x64.exe that came together in the installation of Oracle12cR1.

Doing this, I was able to install the Oracle12cR2 without problems on Windows10.

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same problem that oracle client did not install successful.
It stops with error `[INS-20802] Oracle Net-Konfigurationsassistent nicht erfolgreich`.

Just press button `Überspringen/Skip` a few times - it installs the needed dlls anyway. Then close/finish the installation.
Now you can start oracle/SQL Developer.