# #[INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed during installing oracle12c on windows7. Can any one suggest?

Tags: oracle12c

[INS-20802] Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.

Cause - The plug-in failed in its perform method  Action - Refer to the logs or contact Oracle Support Services.  Log File Location
C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions2016-12-19_11-03-33AM.log

Comment: Please add part of the log file `installActions2016-12-19_11-03-33AM.log` where the actual errors are listed.

Comment: INFO: Read: SYSTEM_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: SYSTEM_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -systemPassword
INFO: Read: PDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: PDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -pdbAdminPassword
INFO: Read: SERVICE_USER_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: SERVICE_USER_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -winServiceUserPassword
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant

Comment: I could not find any error message in the log file.

Comment: This looks like a privilege issue. Are you running installer as Administrator? Oracle Database Configuration Assistant is [one among the list of tools](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTQRF/tools.htm#NTQRF102) which need to be run as Administrator.

Comment: You have to find out error in log file C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\installActions2016-12-19_11-03-33AM.log
In my case, system variable "TNS_ADMIN" variable is store wrong value because once my machine had oracle client installed.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue recently and I tried several of the following methods for resolving the issue :-

1. Disabling Windows UAC
2. Disabling firewall
3. Disabling antivirus - mine was a fresh VM, so disabled Windows Defender
4. Adding localhost IP i.e., 127.0.0.1 to the hosts file etc.

but none of them helped.

At last I found this, which suggested installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5555) and this solved the problem in a matter of seconds! I just had to click 'Retry' on the installation dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For me everything was working fine...I checked for listener, services, path.
Then I tried below and it works...
During installation when Database configuration got failed.
Go to sqlnet.ora file and replace NTS with NONE.

Example :
**SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)**

After that try again installing the database configuration. Click on Retry.

*Note:* If you have installed oracle and skip database configuration failed step then you can go to search bar of window and open Database configuration and try downloading it & it will get installed and will ask for password.
After that you will be able to connect to database.

DONT USE @ IN ORACLE PASSWORD Because when you try to login sql plus it will give error. In case you did that then write your password in inverted commas. ex: "password"

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in some installers, as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754744/111036), which prevents Oracle from installing the required Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable.

The 32bit installer uses the file `install\oraparam.ini`, which contains these lines:

```
#Flags for installing MSVCR80
#MSVCREDIST_LOC flag will provide the name of the exe that is being shipped in stage/ext/bin 
MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x64.exe
```

But the file available under `stage/ext/bin/` is `vcredist_x86.exe`.

So before installing, edit the `install\oraparam.ini` file, and replace `_x64` with `_x86` in that line to get:

```
MSVCREDIST_LOC=vcredist_x86.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @disha, this worked for me:

```
    Go to sqlnet.ora file and replace NTS with NONE.

    Example : SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

    After that try again installing the database configuration. 
    Click on Retry.
```

also tried @mivk advice on the vcredist install path and made sure that I had the same version as the installer provides, when I tried to install this it failed as there was a newer version already installed. anyway with the correct version and this it worked. using a created windows account in the install seems to be the common thread to this issue though using a virtual account I didnt have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the install location worked for me!
New Location: "C:\app"

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to install Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) or (x64)

Answer (score 0):

if you get this error during 19c installation Check if there is an already running listener and stop the listener, then retry the installation . This worked for me